# How to replace the soon-to-be deprecated Salesforce functionalities provided by Live Offers and Live Coupons?

Tags: salesforce, live, coupon, ampscript

With respect to Salseforce's Live Offers and Live Coupons being deprecated in 2020, I am looking for replacement functionality to provide the same features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/199828/send-a-coupon-claim-row) post where the answer does not make sense.  Here's why:  the suggested answer recommended adding a `For` loop to the process.  That would add an additional loop to the process, the first being the auto-iteration through the subscriber list. The additional `For` loop would loop through all coupon codes for each subscriber.  Not optimal.

However the use of the [ClaimRow()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTkRD.png) function is key here, where it auto-populates the  `ClaimedDate` attribute with the date claimed and the `IsClaimed` attribute to `true`.

> This function returns a single row from a Data Extension and reserves
>   the values to prevent them from being used by another operation. If a
>   row is found and is unclaimed, the designated claimed column is set to
>   true and data from that row is returned. If no unclaimed rows are
>   available in the Data Extension, this function will return an error.
>   Claimed rows can be used again if the designated claimed column
>   changes back to false.

The row is also locked during this process.

[image: Coupon Data Extension]

This function is primarily used for assigning unique coupon codes to an audience at send time and recording other pertinent data from the send context.

Using the `ClaimRow` function and the email address from the initial subscriber loop, I was able to update the coupons table:

```
 SET @CouponRow = ClaimRow("CouponsTest2DE", 'IsClaimed', 'SubscriberKey', emailaddr)
```

Where `emailaddr` is the subscriber's email address from the initial subscriber list iterator.